# Eclipse not working on windows 7 professional 64 bit and showing returned exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse for c/c++ developer, but even after completing all the required installation including JRT latest version, eclipse is not running and it shows the following dialog box.

[image]

please help me out of it.. earlier i was using pelles c IDE, but now i really want to use eclipse.
my PC configurations
OS- Windows 7 professional 64-bit
intel core i3 fifth generation

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed java, did you use the proper path directory? Also, make sure you used the proper configuration. If you are using a 64-bit JRT, download the corresponding 64-bit Eclipse program, same goes for the 32-bit program. This tends to be a common issue.

Comment: If it helped you, please accept this answer.